# Query for this table

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to write query for below table that give below result , means when a person has record for year 93 just show it but if hasn't record give year 92

Table :
[image]

Result :
[image]

Comment: what's your problem? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: how to write a query that give this result?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Currently it is unclear what your problem is.

Comment: It would be easier for you to get more answers here if you could explain your problem in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.code,t.name,t.year
FROM (SELECT s.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.name
                                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN s.year = 92 then 1
                                                  WHEN s.year = 93 then 2
                                                  ELSE 3
                                             END) as rnk
      FROM YourTable s) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

I also took the cases when there is more years then `92,93` (prioritized last)